# Align Buttons from different cells in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uibutton

I have two buttons which are on different cells from the table and I want them aligned .

The first cell is consisted from 3 buttons and I just set them equal width all good..
But for the other one from bellow i want to set it the same alignment as the one above.

First i've tried to save the width of that current view and set it to the button , but didn't work:

```
let curentWidth = self.viewThatneedsToBeDivided.bounds.width / 3
self.optionBtnCommon.frame.size.width = CGFloat(curentWidth)
```

Then I've tried to set a constraint, which indeed it seems it is given me the size right but the alignment is just bad.

```
let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint (item: optionBtnCommon, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: curentWidth)
self.optionBtnCommon.superview?.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
self.optionBtnCommon.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
self.viewThatneedsToBeDivided.layoutIfNeeded()
```

[image: cell from bellow]

[image: cell from above]

[image: result]

Comment: Please set the Leading constrain of first button (from left to right) in both the cell and try to give the exact same const value to that layout constrain. Both the button will be automatically aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about check images you have displayed in your question.

[image]

Keep in mind that setting center alignment of button as you have done using following code

```
self.optionBtnCommon.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
```

1. If center alignment is must, then keep in mind that leading and
   width constraint of button must me same, only then these images will
   be aligned.
2. If leading is same but width is different then you must keep alignment left.
3. Or you have third option to set image insets in button property to manually adjust alignment.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to relate them directly as they are in different cells but you have a few of options:

1. Change the constraints so that instead of being related to each other (equal width) they are related to the cell (each one is 0.33 the width of the cell or a sub view).  You can then give the same constraint to the individual button.  Basically you need make them related to something consistent between the two and the only thing is the cell.
2. You could fake it with hidden views.  So add the button and then two other views and setup the constraints the same.  Then make those other views hidden (or clear colour if needed).
3. Look into setting up some layout guides.  These are better to use than dummy views really.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all the buttons into the same cell, embed the first three in a horizontal stack view, same for the second three and embed the two stack views into a vertical stack view. That should give you the necessary power to align them properly.

Comment: While you could do that I assume they are in different cells for a valid reason i.e. the cells represent different items in the data.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth as he said. Different functionality. So no , @ mistakeNot , your answer is not good